# To NULL particular fields in retrieval time in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select isnull(column1,'')+','+isnull(column2,'')+','+isnull(column3,'') AS column4 from table
```

From the above query, I am getting what I need, which is really good. But the thing here is if all the columns all `NULL` I am getting commas which I have used to separate the fields.

I want comma is to be replaced with `NULL` when every field is `NULL`. Can anyone help me in this? thank you!

Comment: This is a bit tricky, because you only want commas *between* values. The way to go is to add each value with a comma (leading or trailing) to the string and then remove the spare comma (first or last character) from the result. Like shown in Gordon Linoff's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might pack the `+ ','` into the `ISNULL()`

```
select isnull(column1+',','')+isnull(column2+',','')+isnull(column3,'') AS column4 from table
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `stuff()` like this:

```
select stuff((coalesce(',' + col1, '') + 
              coalesce(',' + col2, '') +
              coalesce(',' + col3, '')
             ), 1, 1, '')
```

Other databases often have a function called `concat_ws()` that does this as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with CASE EXPRESSION:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column1 is not null then column1 + ',' else '' end +
       CASE WHEN column2 is not null then column2 + ',' else '' end +
       CASE WHEN column3 is not null then column3 else '' end as column4
```

Answer (score 2):

First count number of spaces in name and add it to the count and you will get the result.you can also trim the string if needed

```
declare @count as int
declare @spaceCount as int

select @count =(LEN('amjad habib'))
select @spaceCount =@count-LEN(REPLACE('amjad habib', ' ', ''))

SELECT SUBSTRING('amjad habib',1 , 8 + @spaceCount )
```